# python, using seaborn or plotly to show graphs for medication points over time

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn

I'm trying to plot my heart rate and steps against when i have coffee.

The dataset is like this,

```
    heartRate   steps   coffee
created         
2020-04-14 06:03:00 71.0    NaN 0
2020-04-14 09:03:00 72.0    NaN 1
2020-04-14 09:55:00 61.0    NaN 1
2020-04-14 09:58:00 67.0    NaN 1
2020-04-14 10:01:00 82.0    NaN 2
```

Where 1 is the hour i had coffee and 2 is 4 hours after and 0 is no coffee.

Currently I'm trying to plot these points out like this,

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")

# Load an example dataset with long-form data
fmri = tester

# Plot the responses for different events and regions
sns.lineplot(x="created", y="heartRate", style="medication",
             data=fmri)
```

But this is giving me a unreadable graph like this,

[image]

I'd love to have this be more readable - what am i doing wrong with this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps better take matplotlib. There you can play around with the graph size and the marker and line width to optimize and adjust.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta as delta

font = {'family' : 'Arial',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 60}    
rc('font', **font)    
ndays = 1000
start = datetime(2018, 12, 1)
dates = [start - delta(days = x) for x in range(0, ndays)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time':dates,
                   'heartrate':np.random.randint(60,70,len(dates)),
                   'coffee':np.random.randint(0,2,len(dates))})

df['heartrate_coff'] = df['heartrate']
df['heartrate_nocoff'] = df['heartrate']
df.loc[df['coffee'].values==0,['heartrate_coff'] ]= np.nan
df.loc[df['coffee'].values==1,['heartrate_nocoff']]= np.nan

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(200, 10), 
                 dpi=9, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(df['time'].values , df['heartrate'].values,'k-', linewidth=10)   
plt.plot(df['time'].values , df['heartrate_coff'].values,'rd',markersize=30)   
plt.plot(df['time'].values , df['heartrate_coff'].values,'rd-', linewidth=20)   
plt.plot(df['time'].values , df['heartrate_nocoff'].values,'ko',markersize=10)   
plt.xticks(rotation=-10)
```

[image]